# Nested while loop of i and j in python

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, nested-loops

I have a nested while loop which ultimately will generate the following at the end of the loop:

```
>>>
i=1;j=1
i=1;j=2
i=2;j=1
i=2;j=2
i=2;j=3
i=3;j=1
i=3;j=2
i=3;j=3
Done!
>>>
```

how do i accomplish this output using a nested while loop

Comment: Why would you use `while` for this?

Comment: If you *have* a nested while loop that will do that, what are you asking us for?

Comment: If I am not wrong `i=1;j=3` is missing from the output?

Answer (score 1):

with while loop:

```
i = 1
while i < 4:
    j = 1
    while j < min(i+2, 4):
        print "i={};j={}".format(i, j)
        j += 1
    i += 1
print "Done!"
```

...and better solution with `for x in range()` loop:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1, min(i+2, 4)):
        print "i={};j={}".format(i, j)
print "Done!"
```

Comment: Why would you post an answer that is very similar to the one already given ?

Comment: 1) because id didn't see your answer yet when I was posting mine; 2) because your answer is wrong, gives different result that are expected as stated in question